# Counting numbers in a line

Tags: java

I'm reading my game map

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.internal("data/" + level + ".txt");
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(file.readString());
        while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            String type = tokens.nextToken();
            if(type.equals("Car")){
                carLiist.add(new Car(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Float.parseFloat(tokens.nextToken()), Float.parseFloat(tokens.nextToken())));
            }
```

And here is my text file

```
Block 0 0
Block 64 0
Car 1 5 9 5
Car 1 5 2
Block 1 
Car 7
```

Is it possible in java to count number in each line?
**EDIT:**
How I need to get whole line using stringtokenizer? Here what I'm trying to do, but I get only first word in each line

```
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            String type = tokens.nextToken();
            System.out.println(type);
            if(type.equals("Block")){
                //System.out.println(type);
                list.add(new Brick(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken())));
```

Comment: There's probably not a prexisting method, but you can very much write one yourself. Just read a line at a time. Then split the line string into an array list of strings. Loop the array list and check if each one is a number or not.

Comment: I would do what @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc mentioned. You can use Apache's [StringUtils#isNumeric](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric(java.lang.String)) to see if the numbers are numeric

Comment: But how I need to get characters form the line using StringTokenizer ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Java provides a method to check whether a character is digit or not. Check the character and and increase count if its digit like this:

```
int digitCount = 0;
if(isDigit(characterToCheck)) {
    digitCount++;
}
```

Method: `boolean isDigit(char ch)`. See [here for example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isdigit.htm)

Comment: This requires additional code for handing numbers with more than one digit, like the example has 64.

Comment: Ok but how I need to get wholeline using StringTokenizer. I just get first word, but I don't get numbers in that line